# Formatting xml rest return

Tags: php, html, xml, rest

I created php code that gets a rest xml response. The code follows:

```
<table valign="top" cellpadding="10"  style=" padding:0px 15px;"><tr></tr><tr>

<?php $song = str_replace(' ', '+', $post['title']);
$url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks&limit=5&api_key=*************";

$xml=simplexml_load_file("$url");

foreach($xml->tracks->track as $track){
    foreach($track->name as $name) {
        $image = $track->image;
        $link = str_replace(' ', '-', $name); 
        echo "<th width='20%' valign='top'><img src='$image' alt='$name' height='90' width='90'></br></br><a href='http://www.mp3jive.com/music/download/1/$link.html'>$name</a></th>";
    }
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

It retrieves xml such as the following:

```
<lfm status="ok">
    <tracks page="1" perPage="5" totalPages="200" total="1000">
        <track><name>Chandelier</name><duration>216</duration><playcount>109163</playcount><listeners>38691</listeners><mbid>4d507ca4-0d95-494c-b97b-e2fa50c926c1</mbid><url>http://www.last.fm/music/Sia/_/Chandelier</url><streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable><artist><name>Sia</name><mbid>2f548675-008d-4332-876c-108b0c7ab9c5</mbid><url>http://www.last.fm/music/Sia</url></artist><image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/98738409.png</image><image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/98738409.png</image><image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/98738409.png</image><image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/98738409.png</image></track>
        <track><name>Do I Wanna Know?</name><duration>273</duration><playcount>64234</playcount><listeners>33378</listeners><mbid>575d24ee-cf80-48ad-beeb-9295c7d05b35</mbid><url>http://www.last.fm/music/Arctic+Monkeys/_/Do+I+Wanna+Know%3F</url><streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable><artist><name>Arctic Monkeys</name><mbid>ada7a83c-e3e1-40f1-93f9-3e73dbc9298a</mbid><url>http://www.last.fm/music/Arctic+Monkeys</url></artist><image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/92744747.png</image><image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/92744747.png</image><image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/92744747.png</image><image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/92744747.png</image></track>
        <track><name>A Sky Full of Stars</name><duration>268</duration><playcount>60604</playcount><listeners>30131</listeners><mbid>d0d9e6e7-47c1-4470-9124-d10613c09ece</mbid><url>http://www.last.fm/music/Coldplay/_/A+Sky+Full+of+Stars</url><streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable><artist><name>Coldplay</name><mbid>cc197bad-dc9c-440d-a5b5-d52ba2e14234</mbid><url>http://www.last.fm/music/Coldplay</url></artist><image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/99319661.png</image><image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/99319661.png</image><image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/99319661.png</image><image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/99319661.png</image></track>
        <track><name>Stay with Me</name><duration>173</duration><playcount>70310</playcount><listeners>30071</listeners><mbid>c8dbf2c6-cbd2-48d2-ae04-e3098e29e306</mbid><url>http://www.last.fm/music/Sam+Smith/_/Stay+with+Me</url><streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable><artist><name>Sam Smith</name><mbid>5a85c140-dcf9-4dd2-b2c8-aff0471549f3</mbid><url>http://www.last.fm/music/Sam+Smith</url></artist><image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/99230175.png</image><image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/99230175.png</image><image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/99230175.png</image><image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/99230175.png</image></track>
        <track><name>Summer</name><duration>224</duration><playcount>57584</playcount><listeners>29519</listeners><mbid>9947d625-1d29-45df-a988-6e907fd1fea1</mbid><url>http://www.last.fm/music/Calvin+Harris/_/Summer</url><streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable><artist><name>Calvin Harris</name><mbid>8dd98bdc-80ec-4e93-8509-2f46bafc09a7</mbid><url>http://www.last.fm/music/Calvin+Harris</url></artist><image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/97561221.png</image><image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/97561221.png</image><image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/97561221.png</image><image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/97561221.png</image></track>
    </tracks>
</lfm>
```

This code when grabbing the image gets the small image. I would like it to grab the large image. How can I easily alter it to do so. Thanks.

Comment: You really shouldn't put your API key to be seen everywhere.

Comment: `foreach($track->image as $image) { $attrs = $image->attributes(); if($attrs['size'] == 'large')( ... `. Or fetch with an XPath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the large file is always the 3rd, you could simply put:

```
foreach($xml->tracks->track as $track){
    foreach($track->name as $name) {
        $image = $track->image[2]; // it is the third image
        $link = str_replace(' ', '-', $name); 
        echo "<th width='20%' valign='top'><img src='$image' alt='$name' height='90' width='90'></br></br><a href='http://www.mp3jive.com/music/download/1/$link.html'>$name</a></th>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution, access the image by its index:

```
$image = $track->image[2]; // large

$image = $track->image[3]; // extralarge
```